# Spark StorageLevel - When to use MEMORY_ONLY_2, MEMORY_AND_DISK_2 etc?

Tags: apache-spark, storage, rdd

The advantage of `RDD` is by default Resilient, it can rebuild the broken partition based on lineage graph.

Then why do we need to use this `Storage Levels` like `MEMORY_ONLY_2`, `MEMORY_AND_DISK_2` etc, this is basically to replicate each partition on two cluster nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Use it if you need higher reliability. To restore the data if any node refused and not recalculate RDD.